Possible Hitchcock anthology short story written before 1970 about newlyweds honeymooning In the Caribbean
I am searching for a short story written before 1970.  It may have been featured in an Alfred Hitchcock anthology of scary stories.
It was about a young newlywed couple honeymooning on a Caribbean island, maybe Haiti or the West Indies. In the story the young bride has a spell placed on her by a local practitioner of voodoo or black magic. I think the story ends with the bride leaving her husband under a voodoo spell and going to a black magic priest.
